# If I manually paste files into Dropbox that are already synced on other machines will they create conflicts?

Tags: dropbox

I've got 200gb of files saved in Dropbox and synced across various machines.

One of the machines is about to have a hard drive swap (500gb to 1tb) and clean install of OS.

We don't have the fastest internet connection (c. 10mbps down, 1 up) so I don't want to have to download all the files again over the internet.

Because I've got the files backed up on another HD (prior to doing the clean install of OS) can i just copy the files in Dropbox from the external HD to the new HD on the computer, or will this cause a whole bunch of conflict files to occur in Dropbox ?

OS wise I'm running OSX10.10

(I've posted this in web apps as the conflict files issue is a core Dropbox issue which is a web app, but if you feel there is a better place for this question please advise).

Comment: Dropbox also supports LAN Sync. So if you have another machine running Dropbox in the same network with all the files present, Dropbox would download from that machine, instead of the internet: https://www.dropbox.com/help/137

Answer (score -1):

You should take image of Dropbox folder and paste it into new HDD otherwise there will be duplication.